# How to display subcategories rather than parent categories on product category loop on the homepage?

Tags: wordpress, categories, product

I am running the Superstore theme and would like to know how I can display subcategories rather than top level categories on the product categories loop? I have it set up like thumbnails on the homepage where customers can click on it, kind of like a menu, but it will only let me display the top level category pictures and not the subcategories which is what I really want to display.

I will also need to know how to pick and choose what subcategory pictures to display as I wont need all of them to display.

Answer (score 0):

From the 'Appearance' menu on the left-hand side of the Dashboard, select the 'Menus' option to bring up the Menu Editor.

You must **define a MENU** and **choose** which items you want to add 
(Categories and/or Sub-Categories and/or Posts and/or Links)

[A guide to set up a WordPress Menu (codex.wordpress.org)](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide)

Hope this help you.